# Laravel 4 - moving index.php to subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, localhost

I'm trying to create a static site generator, where the index.php file is under `public/admin`, and static files go under `public`.

I changed the `public` setting in `paths.php` to:

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public/admin',
```

And in `index.php` changed:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

to:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
```

to reflect the new folder structure. Now, when I visit `/public/admin` I get redirected to `/admin` and get a 404 not found.

Comment: why don't you just solve this by using a `Route::get('/admin', ...)`?

Comment: Ah, you are absolutely right. Sometimes I don't see the easy solution...

Answer (score 1):

for completion's sake:

you might be better off just using `Route::get('/admin', ...)` as the files still need to be served.